# Insert information from hash into iteration

Tags: ruby

I am trying to insert information from a hash `monthly_multipliers` into an iterator.

```
month_multipliers = { april: 1, may: 2, june: 3, july: 4, august: 5, september: 6, october: 7, november: 8, december: 9, january: 10, february: 11, march: 12}
months = ['april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december', 'january', 'february', 'march']
```

I then iterate through each month, and need to inject the monthly multiplier for each month, so june would be 3 august 5 etc.

```
months.each do |month|
  instance_variable_set :"@#{month}_income", (monthly_new_account_income * month_multipliers[month]) + previous_years_monthly_income
end
```

This bit doesn't work

```
 month_multipliers[month])
```

I tried sending and getting an instance variable, but cannot get the format right.

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: can you explain more? what doesnt work about it? is there an error is it a different value than you expect?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

`month_multipliers` has keys in `Symbol` objects, but `months` has keys as `String` objects. Use either all `Symbol` or `String` objects or convert keys to the correct object before retrieving the values from the hash.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
@month_multipliers[month.to_sym]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your issue, youre using symbolic keys with string values. you can directly iterate over the month_multiplier for simplicity

```
month_multipliers.each_pair do |month, multiplier|
  instance_variable_set :"@#{month}_income", (monthly_new_account_income * multiplier) + previous_years_monthly_income
end
```